# How to prevent indentation of @ access specifiers?

Tags: objective-c, code-formatting, uncrustify

In a class declaration like this:

```
@interface MyView : NSView
{
@private
    id observedObject;
}

@end
```

when I run uncrustify on it the @private specifier is indented even though I'd like to keep it in its default column. Which uncrustify option controls that? I added a line `indent_access_spec = 0` but that doesn't seem to affect cases like mine (docs say this is for specifiers followed by color, so this is probably for C++, not Objective-C).

Comment: Just as an aside: There's no more reason to expose private ivars in the `@interface`. You can now put them into the `@implementation` where other files can't see them.